# b-input name attribute not working buefy

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bulma

I want to put a `name="name"` attribute in a [buefy](https://buefy.github.io/#/) input control. I have so far, not managed to make it work.

```
<b-field label="Fullname">
   <b-input
      value=""
      icon="face"
      name="name">
   </b-input>
</b-field>
```

It sends empty values and I get an error in laravel:

```
"Column 'name' cannot be null"
```

It worked when I tried using a native html input control.

I have also tried using developer tools to inspect the DOM, it appears, the b-input control does not have a name.

How do I solve this?

Edit:
I had vue@2.1.10 and for buefy you need 2.4, that's why I got this bug. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: How are you sending the value to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Use [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) to bind your component to your data.

In your `<template>...</template>`:

```
<b-field label="Fullname">
    <b-input
      v-model="fullname"
      icon="face">
    </b-input>
</b-field>
```

In your `<script>...</script>`:

```
data () {
   fullname: null,

   //some more state...
},
```